# DotNetNuke Installation database connection error

Tags: asp.net, database, dotnetnuke

I have been trying to install DNN 7 but it got stucked at the first step of installation. Giving the error 
"No valid default database connection detected. Standard Database setup option is unavailable Database Connection Error"

ERROR:Index #: 0 Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Class: 20 Number: 53 Message:

Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: what type of database are you using.  is this a local installation or a remote installation.  Need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs if you try to install DNN using SQL Express, but you don't have SQL express installed, or you don't have it installed with the default instance name.

You can do one of the following things.

1) Install SQL Express
2) Connect to a different database server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Chris. I don't have SQL Express installed because i am using SQL Server Enterprise. It is installed with the default instance name.

Answer (score 0):

if you have already installed the database then go to SQL server and select `Server Name = .\sqlexpress` and open it. Once it opens, go to `Security=>Logins=>Right Click` on `sa` and select `properties`. It will open a dialog. Select `Status=>` and check `Login Enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

just because you are writing wrong server name! mostly you should delete "." before "/" mark
like this : localhost\sqlexpress  not localhost.\sqlexpress

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERVER Management Studio 19 And SQL Express
**Database Username and Password : sa and sa@123**
**If You Don't Know That Set :ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = 'new_password'; using this query.**

Download : https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/tree/v9.11.2 DNNSoftware from this link
Internet Information Services[IIS] Manager
Mozilla Firefox

I have been trying to install DNN 7 but it got stucked at the first step of installation. Giving the error "No valid default database connection detected. Standard Database setup option is unavailable Database Connection Error"

ERROR:Index #: 0 Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Class: 20 Number: 53 Message:

Anyone knows what to do?

I have Passed 2 day's to solve this error of database information on my installation wizard then i found the easiest solution of it.

I've already installed SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 19 in my device. That's why i don't know that username and password i was passing as per the documentation https://docs.dnncommunity.org/content/tutorials/server/setup/run-installation-wizard/index.html
Database Username as: MyDNNSQLUser and Password as: MyDNNSQLUser **insted of** passing
**Database Username and Password : sa and sa@123**

I Recommed you to prefer this doc https://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/administrators/control-bar-to-persona-bar.html if you're begginer for this.

Thank You...