# DnnSoftware Installation and Setup

Tags: asp.net-core, content-management-system

I'm getting error while i am installing dnnsoftware https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/download this is the link of download and setup of it.
To make easy i followed https://docs.dnncommunity.org/content/tutorials/server/setup/run-installation-wizard/index.html this documentation from their official site and now i am getting error from past 2 day's.
ERROR:Index #: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Class: 20
Number: 3
Message:Unable to connect to database.

I have completed steps and setup my IIS Server, SSMS and other things mentioned. https://docs.dnncommunity.org/content/tutorials/server/setup/run-installation-wizard/index.html
i want to solve this error and this is scrrenshot

```
I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985837/dotnetnuke-installation-database-connection-error to solve but it is not working still...
```